# Could not find Heroku <> = 0 Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, windows-7

Heroku was working well but suddenly it stops today.
When I try to run something like `heroku logs` there is an error comming out.

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:
in `to_specs': Could not find heroku (>= 0) amongst [actionmailer-3.2.13, action
pack-3.2.13, activeadmin-0.6.1, activeadmin-mongoid-0.2.0, activemodel-3.2.13, a
ctiverecord-3.2.13, activeresource-3.2.13, activesupport-3.2.13, arbre-1.0.1, ar
el-3.0.2, bcrypt-ruby-3.1.2-x86-mingw32, bourbon-3.1.8, bson-1.9.2, bson_ext-1.9
.2, builder-3.0.4, bundle-0.0.1, bundler-1.3.4, coffee-rails-3.2.2, coffee-scrip
t-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.6.3, devise-3.0.2, erubis-2.7.0, execjs-2.0.2, f
araday-0.8.8, font-awesome-rails-3.2.1.3, font_assets-0.1.10, formtastic-2.2.1,
has_scope-0.6.0.rc, hashie-2.0.5, hike-1.2.3, httpauth-0.2.0, i18n-0.6.1, inheri
ted_resources-1.4.1, journey-1.0.4, jquery-rails-2.3.0, json-1.8.0, jwt-0.1.8, k
aminari-0.14.1, mail-2.5.4, meta-tags-1.5.0, meta_search-1.1.3, mime-types-1.25,
 mongoid-3.0.23, moped-1.5.1, multi_json-1.8.0, multipart-post-1.2.0, oauth2-0.8
.1, omniauth-1.1.4, omniauth-facebook-1.4.1, omniauth-oauth2-1.1.1, origin-1.1.0
, orm_adapter-0.4.0, polyamorous-0.5.0, polyglot-0.3.3, rack-1.4.5, rack-cache-1
.2, rack-ssl-1.3.3, rack-test-0.6.2, rails-3.2.13, rails_12factor-0.0.2, rails_s
erve_static_assets-0.0.1, rails_stdout_logging-0.0.2, railties-3.2.13, rake-10.1
.0, rdoc-3.12.2, responders-1.0.0, sass-3.2.11, sass-rails-3.2.6, sprockets-2.2.
2, thor-0.18.1, tilt-1.4.1, treetop-1.4.15, tzinfo-0.3.37, uglifier-2.2.1, warde
n-1.2.3] (Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/depen
dency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:12
31:in `gem'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/heroku:22:in `<main>'
```

I used the Heroku Toolbelt and it was fine until today.

My %PATH% variable is:

```
C:\>echo %PATH%
C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby
1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\Git
\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windo
ws;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Progr
am Files\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files\git\cmd
```

Do you have suggestions?.

Thank you.